# Issue updating a data attribute via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

I want to get data via ajax and update a div attribute `data-used`, but it have not change and in the console, it shows:

> TypeError: "#powerv1".data is not a function

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'showjson.php',
  data: "power=10",
  dataType: 'json',

  success: function(datap){
    var p1value= datap.power;
    ('#powerv1').data('used',p1value);
    //('#powerv1').attr('data-used',p1value); <--also tested , same error
  }

});
```

```html
<div class="card"><h5 class="card-header"> Area 1</h5>
  <h2 class="mb-0">
    <div class='Preview'>
      <div class='GaugeMeter' id='powerv1' name='powerv1' data-size='200' data-theme='Green-Red' data-width='15'data-append='W' data-label='Watt'_color='#FF0000' data-showvalue=true data-total=1000 data-used=100></div>
    </div>
  </h2>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('#powerv1').data`

Comment: Sorry , it still not work ...but the type error have disappear

Comment: Works for me. What's the value of `datap`? What does `console.log($('#powerv1').data('used'))` output afterwards?

Comment: Incidentally, if you are expecting to see changes in the DOM, note that jQuery's [`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) "does not affect attributes in the DOM". For that, use [`attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

[From the docs:](https://api.jquery.com/data/#entry-longdesc)

> Using the data() method to update data does not affect attributes in
>   the DOM. To set a data-* attribute value, use attr.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'showjson.php',
  data: "power=10",
  dataType: 'json',

  success: function(datap){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(datap)); // log the response to console.
    var p1value = datap.power;
    $('#powerv1').data('used',p1value);
    $('#powerv1').attr('data-used', p1value);
  }

});
```